# mysql count help

Tags: mysql, count, aggregate-functions

I am trying to count the number of rows in a table that have an area, how can I achieve this, I currently have this query written,

```
SELECT DISTINCT area 
  FROM cv 
 WHERE status = 'SHOW' 
   AND is_complete = 'TRUE' 
ORDER BY area ASC
```

This query currently returns,

```
area
------------------
West Yorkshire  
Lanchashire
```

What I am wanting is something like,

```
area             Number
------------------------
West Yorkshire   19000  
Lancashire       7000
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select area, count(*)
from cv
where status = 'SHOW' 
    and is_complete = 'TRUE' 
group by area
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT area, COUNT(area)
  FROM cv
WHERE status = 'SHOW'
  AND is_complete = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY area
```

Count of area will count only non null values

Comment: OTOH, when you use GROUP BY you'll get a "NULL, 0" row, which you might not want. (At least in SQL Server, MySQL may exhibit different behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT area, COUNT(area)
  FROM cv
WHERE status = 'SHOW'
  AND is_complete = 'TRUE'
  AND area IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY area
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql distinct will list only the diffent values in a table, you original query will need to  have count() and group by as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT area, count(*) 
  FROM cv
.....

group by area
```

alternatively, Red Filer and gkrogers answer is good as well.

Comment: Don't need DISTINCT on a column you're grouping by